# SQL Laravel Leaderboard how to Optimize?

Tags: jquery, sql, laravel

I have a project that i am Calling Results from an **SQL** Database. 
I have a **results page** that pulls **race results** from a database.

[image]

Then I use very basic JQuery to pull these results into a Styled home page that reloads the Results page every 1000 millisecs.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      refreshTable();
    });

    function refreshTable(){
        $('#tableHolder').load('results/Birchwood2017', function(){
           setTimeout(refreshTable, 1000);
        });
    }
```

I would like to know if this is good or bad would this create a slow database if lets say 100 devices call the page and the query every 1000 millisecs or is there a better and more optimized way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to cache results and when tables updated regenerate the results and cache it again. And it will be simple static result every request. If your application doesn't responsible to insert or update records you can use mysql triggers for that.